# Access violation while storing data from CSV

Tags: c, csv, access-violation

I am trying to store data from a CSV file and ran into an access violation. The first image was shows how the memory is allocated, the second shows the problem area and the third is the spot in the csv where the problem occurred. Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image: snip of my VS]

[image: data at problem location]

Comment: `AllCurrentData[newLineCount].data[tabCount]` is pointing to `NULL` (0x00000000).  You need to check the result of the malloc call before attempting to use it.

Comment: What are `NUM_PRODUCTS` and `COLUMNS`? Looks like you have hard coded the number of both and that number is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the first loop that does the "pre-allocation" may have an error.  The following allocation:

```
AllCurrentData[newLineCOunt].data = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char));
```

should, I believe, be this:

```
AllCurrentData[newLineCOunt].data = malloc(COLUMNS * sizeof(char*));
```

Comment: @TinMan:  I'm glad it worked.  Since the original allocation was too small, the assignments (via malloc) would eventually write past the end of allocated memory ... and then anything can happen.